Initialization failed: Error initializing stage: generate grasp pose: invalid pregrasp: unknown state ''
Hi I am currently working with Moveit Task Constructor package at ROS Noetic dist. I want to folow this tutorial but instead of using the panda robot, I would like to use my robot. To do that I first created a configuration folder for my robot with Moveit Setup Asistant and then cloned the git page codes into my workspace called optobot_pnp. Later I changed the related parts with Panda robot to my robot. However, whenever I try to launch pick_place_demo.launch file which starts the tasks for rviz, it gaves me an error which is:
[ERROR] [1719232075.344341022]: unknown state '' Exception thrown. [ERROR] [1719232075.344478937]: Initialization failed: Error initializing stage: generate grasp pose: invalid pregrasp: unknown state ''

[ INFO] [1719232075.344514204]: Initialization failed [pick_place_demo-1] process has died [pid 41629, exit code 1, cmd /home/erkbaarge/optobot_ws/devel/lib/optobot_pnp/pick_place_demo
__name:=pick_place_demo __log:=/home/erkbaarge/.ros/log/25ed2a66-3225-11ef-aa7a-2dae64576486/pick_place_demo-1.log]. log file: /home/erkbaarge/.ros/log/25ed2a66-3225-11ef-aa7a-2dae64576486/pick_place_demo-1*.log

It says " unknown state '' " but I dont have a state that is named like that and I dont get any other error mesages. And I cant see any other errors which might cause this.
My codes:
demo.launch:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>
  <!-- Load panda demo with MTC's execution capability -->
  <include file="$(find optobot_configurations)/launch/demo.launch">
    <arg name="use_rviz" value="false"/>
  </include>
  <param name="move_group/capabilities" value="move_group/ExecuteTaskSolutionCapability" />

  <!-- Run rviz with prepared config -->
  <include file="$(find optobot_configurations)/launch/moveit_rviz.launch">
    <arg name="rviz_config" value="$(find optobot_pnp)/config/mtc.rviz" />
  </include>
</launch>

pick_place_demo.launch:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>
  <!-- Run MTC pick and place -->
  <node name="pick_place_demo" pkg="optobot_pnp" type="pick_place_demo" output="screen">
    <param name="execute" value="true" />
    <rosparam command="load" file="$(find optobot_pnp)/config/optobot_config.yaml" />
    <param name="robot_description_semantic" textfile="/home/erkbaarge/optobot_ws/src/core/optobot_configurations/config/Optobot.srdf" />
  </node>
  
</launch>

optobot_config.yaml:
# Total planning attempts
max_solutions: 10

# Planning group and link names
arm_group_name: "arm"
eef_name: "end_effector"
hand_group_name: "hand"
hand_frame: "gripdon1"

# Poses with actual joint values
hand_open_pose:
  gripdon1: -0.6981
hand_close_pose:
  gripdon1: 0.1
arm_home_pose:
  doner12: -0.25
  doner23: -0.25
  doner34: -1.0
  doner45: 0.25
  doner56: 2.7
  doner67: 0.55
  donerson: 0.0

# Scene frames
world_frame: "world"
table_reference_frame: "world"
object_reference_frame: "world"
surface_link: "table"

# Collision object for picking
# CYLINDER object specifications
object_name: "object"
object_dimensions: [0.25, 0.02] # [height, radius]
object_pose: [0.5, -0.25, 0.0, 0, 0, 0]

# Table model
spawn_table: true
table_name: "table"
table_dimensions: [0.4, 0.5, 0.1]  # [length, width, height]
table_pose: [0.5, -0.25, 0, 0, 0, 0]

# Gripper grasp frame transform [x,y,z,r,p,y]
grasp_frame_transform: [0, 0, 0.1, 1.571, 0.785, 1.571]

# Place pose [x,y,z,r,p,y]
place_pose: [0.6, -0.15, 0, 0, 0, 0]
place_surface_offset: 0.0001 # place offset from table

# Valid distance range when approaching an object for picking
approach_object_min_dist: 0.1
approach_object_max_dist: 0.15

# Valid height range when lifting an object after pick
lift_object_min_dist: 0.01
lift_object_max_dist: 0.1

my pick_place_demo.cpp and pick_place_task.cpp files are exactly same as configurated at github page.
